# Rails use not condition with before_filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, before-filter

I'm using before_filter in my application. I have a method `logged_in?` which returns true if the user is logged in.

```
def logged_in?
  !!current_user
end

def current_user
  @current_user = (User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]) || false
end
```

Now in my users controller I want an action to execute only if a user is not logged in. For this I want to use the **not** condition with `logged_in?` method in `before_filter` as:

```
before_filter :!(logged_in?)
```

But this gives me an error. I'm resisting creating a new method for not logged in.

Please help me figure out the correct syntax to accomplish this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could pass a block to `before_filter`:

```
before_filter { |c| !c.logged_in? }
```

But this wouldn't really do anything, since the return value from the before filter isn't going anywhere. If you want to execute an action if a user is not logged in, then you should be putting that action into the before_filter.

For example, if the action was to redirect to the login page, path, you could do this:

```
before_filter { |c| redirect_to login_path unless c.logged_in? }
```

That's actually long enough to justify a method of its own:

```
before_filter :login_required

def login_required
  redirect_to login_path unless logged_in?
end
```

Answer (score 18):

While the accepted answer seems to work, I would have done it differently.

```
before_filter :login_required, unless: :logged_in?

def login_required
  redirect_to login_path, notice: 'Please login'
end
```

This will execute the method login_required unless the user is already logged in.  See http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/159805303/before-filter-wisdom for more info.

Comment: If you're using the :login_required method like in the answer above yours, I don't know why you'd bother with the **unless logged_in?** on your before filter.  It has the exact same **unless** clause in both places (before filter and in the method it calls), so you are repeating yourself.  If you tack it onto the before filter, it'll never even get to the method.  It doesn't make a functional difference, but stylistically it's not as [DRY](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/41947/ruby-on-rails-and-dry) and adds unnecessary repeated code.

Comment: Good point, updated my answer to include an updated `login_required` method.

Answer (score 0):

**application_controller.rb**

```
before_filter :authorize

def current_user
   @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
end
   helper_method :current_user

protected
def authorize
   unless User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
     redirect_to login_url, :notice => "Not Authorize Member"
   end
end
```